# How do I send resources to a "Great Work"?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have started building the Arcology project, and I'm producing metal and alloy myself. Normally I export these products to earn money, but does anyone know if I have to set the trade settings to "Use locally" instead of "Export" to make them send the resources to the project?

How long does it take to send those resources? I'm producing around 100kg metal a day, and 2,8t is needed. So it should go pretty fast huh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To send resources to your great work, zoom out to the region view and click on the great work site - this will show you a status screen detailing each of the resources required to build the great work and the quantity of each resource that has already been supplied.

To enable your city to send resources to the great work, you will see on this screen that underneath each resource is a 'power button' (it looks the same as the power buttons to disable buildings). Turn this *on* and you will start sending resources to your great work site.

[image]

Every city in the region that is within range of the great work site will have their own controls for sending resources to the great work site, allowing for a group of people to participate in building a great work, with each potentially providing a different type of resource.

The frequency of delivery of the resources to the Great Work depends entirely on the availability of the resource at the Trade Depot(s) and the number of delivery trucks available to take it there.

As of patched version 10.3, the Trade Depots (resource sink) suffer from a bug that allows the delivery trucks to park at an alternate resource source as well as drive out of the city to an unknown destination and not return.  Therefore, if your delivery truck garages at your Trade Depot are empty (no trucks parked inside), then you should bulldoze the empty garages, rebuild them and they will begin delivering from the Trade Depot again.

Comment: I will add a screenshot of the screen tonight - SimCity won't run via RDP :P

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have clicked on the buttons now, so hopefully they are sending the resources. I was jus wondering if I had to do anything with my trade settings regaring local/import/export. I would love to keep it on export and still resources are sent to the work site.

Comment: I haven't tested that - presumably though if you leave them on export you will be selling all of your resources rather than providing them to the great works site?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah you definitly have to "use locally" and it takes a while for the flow of transfer to the great work, obviously dont sent more than your budget will allow since you'll be taking a hit on export profit.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can build more than one Trade depot, you can assign one for local use to send to the great work area while assign the other one to export some of your product, but you have to make sure you produce enough to keep up with the great work area.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I send resources to a “Great Work”?

[kalina](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108858/133645) has done a great job explaining this in general.

### Local, import or export?

Since no one has tested or elaborated on this I will explain a little further:

> Does anyone know if I have to set the trade settings to "Use locally"
>   instead of "Export" to make them send the resources to the project?

If you set the "Global market deliveries" to export trucks will **not** deliver resources to the Great Works site, but rather leave the city and give you profit for the resources.

If you set the "Global market deliveries" to import trucks will deliver the **imported** resources to the Great Works site.

If you set the "Global market deliveries" to local trucks will deliver the resources to the Great Works site.

> How long does it take to send those resources?

This is hard to say. It will depend on how many Trade depo/ports you have, how many trucks those have and the traffic. The easiest way to find out is to measure the time it will take for one truck to deliver a certain quantity.

*I tested this (today) on the latest updated version of SimCity.*

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to put all of your trade ports to import great works resources you need.